# como llamar un elemento con queryselecctor

Tags: javascript, html

Si tengo una tabla en duro solo esta parte, ya que lo de a continuación del `tbody` lo del `TR` lo  traspaso con javascript, con `createelement`
este elemento ya esta creado en el DOM y hago el llamado al elemento una vez creado,
con la propiedad `document` me funciona hasta la parte del `.tbody` hacia atrás, pero necesito llegar al elemento como tal
y lo llamo de esta forma

donde `.table__rut` es la clase del `td`
y `#rut` el el id del elemento al que quiero llegar

```js
const sss = document.querySelector("#tabla >.tbody>.table__rut >#rut" + id).textContent;
console.log(sss);
```

```html
<table id="tabla" class="table">
  <tr>
    <TH>id</TH>
    <TH>rut</TH>
    <TH>nombre</TH>
    <TH>apellido</TH>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="carrito_content" class="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerda que el atributo `id` de cualquier elemento en un documento HTML **ha de ser siempre único**, por lo tanto la forma de buscarlo es:

```javascript
let id='...';
document.getElementById(`rut${id}`);
```

o, usando querySelector:

```javascript
let id='...';
document.querySelector(`#rut${id}`);
```